# TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound

Tags: ruby, jekyll, tzinfo

today I used *ruby+jekyll* to compile a static web page file. This web page was forked from [academicpages](https://github.com/academicpages/academicpages.github.io). After installing ruby, gem and a series of dependency packages, I used *bundle exec jekyll build* to compile the file. But the time configuration problem keeps popping up. I read many people's questions and answers, and also communicated with ChatGPT. After trying the existing methods, they all ended in failure. Is there a better way to solve the problem?

```
    C:\Users\asus\Desktop\pioneerzhou.github.io>bundle exec jekyll build
Configuration file: C:/Users/asus/Desktop/pioneerzhou.github.io/_config.yml
jekyll 3.9.5 | Error:  No source of timezone data could be found.
Please refer to https://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error.
C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:159:in `rescue in create_default_data_source': No source of timezone data could be found. (TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound)
Please refer to https://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound for help resolving this error.
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:156:in `create_default_data_source'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `get'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:235:in `data_source'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:128:in `get'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/utils/win_tz.rb:16:in `calculate'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll.rb:130:in `set_timezone'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll.rb:118:in `block in configuration'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll.rb:117:in `configuration'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:43:in `configuration_from_options'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_sources/zoneinfo_data_source.rb:252:in `initialize': None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories. (TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound)
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:157:in `new'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:157:in `create_default_data_source'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:55:in `block in get'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `synchronize'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/data_source.rb:54:in `get'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:235:in `data_source'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/tzinfo-2.0.6/lib/tzinfo/timezone.rb:128:in `get'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/utils/win_tz.rb:16:in `calculate'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll.rb:130:in `set_timezone'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll.rb:118:in `block in configuration'
        from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll.rb:117:in `configuration'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:43:in `configuration_from_options'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:29:in `process'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
        from C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.9.5/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Users/asus/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you read https://tzinfo.github.io/datasourcenotfound how to solve the error as suggested in the error message? Do you have the `tzinfo-data` gem installed, as the page explains?

Comment: I have installed the `tzinfo-data` by gem,but  no effect

Comment: `C:\Users\asus>gem install tzinfo-data
Using rubygems directory: C:/Users/asus/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.2.0
Successfully installed tzinfo-data-1.2024.1
Parsing documentation for tzinfo-data-1.2024.1
Done installing documentation for tzinfo-data after 0 seconds
1 gem installed`

Comment: with the help of ChatGPT and stackoverflow，I find a way to solve this problem。

Comment: [Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo/wiki/Resolving-TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound-Errors),this offered solution is effective.First,we must have a file that needs to be compiled,like the C:\Users\asus\Desktop\pioneerzhou.github.io,in this folder,we will find a file called Gemfile.open it by vscode,add `gem 'tzinfo-data'` to the end of the content.Then,enter the command line,type `bundle install` and run it.

Comment: `C:\Users\asus\Desktop\pioneerzhou.github.io>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundle complete! 7 Gemfile dependencies, 99 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.`